# Create new HTML table Column with NODEJS loop

Tags: node.js, html

I need to add a new HTML Table column for every document in Mongod using a NodeJs Loop. I am unable to achieve the same.

I have a form with 10 variables, I have to fix the number of rows as 10 in HTML table but if someone fills the form, the data should be displayed as new column for those 10 rows (Variables)

Comment: Please provide the code you tried.

Comment: I am unable to write the logic,